# I'm using electron for the first time and instead of opening the HTML file it takes to to a blank electron page

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm new to electron and was trying to create a simple code that opens an html file, however instead it opens a blank electron window.

```js
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron

app.on('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({width:800, hight: 600})
  win.loadURL('file://${__dirname}/index.html')
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UFR-8">
  <title>Hey Maaaaaan</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Howdy</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGwfZ.png)

Comment: `${__dirname}` is not being interpolated, because you're using the wrong kind of string. Use backticks instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'file://${__dirname}/index.html'
```

This is just a string. No dirname gets injected here.

Try this instead:

```
const path = require('path');

win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
```

It is the recommended way:
[Electron Guide](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/)